# Android video and audio playback speed is nearly double

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio, video

Yesterday I was showing a video to a friend of mine and something weird happened. As he went to grab my phone while I was holding it he had a few fingers on the screen and something flashed up and flashed away in the time span of about half a second so I wasn't able to exactly read what popped up. Although, since that happened it seems all my video and audio is being played at a high playback speed, I'd say around x2 the normal playback speed.

This isn't just limited to one app either. This occurred in an app called BuzzVideo, but the playback speed is global, in the YouTube app, YouTube Red, etc. I tried a combination of gestures on the screen while on that BuzzVideo app, but nothing seems to change the playback speed.

Do you have any suggestions?

What I've tried:

- Restarting the phone
- Rebooting the phone
- Resetting the data & cache for the app that caused the issue

Comment: Might also add I'm trying to avoid an app data reset as I've disabled notifications for countless apps and have settings that would be very tedious to add back in for certain apps

Comment: If it helps, this is my device specs: http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=bc96-50e4-ffff-ffffb051cabc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accidentally wiping it (factory reset) while attempting to clear all app data, which in turn, fixed it (just not the way I was hoping for).

Now I've gotta manually remove the bloatware from my telecommunications provider and from the phone manufacturer and restore all those nice settings & applications I had.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the same video through the same app and hold it again the way you were- perhaps the dialogue will pop up again and you can catch it this time. I imagine you simply long-pressed for an options menu to come up. Just be ready to let go (or not) when you see it. Should fix your prob.

Comment: Sadly not, already tried that for about 2 hours in total, using 1-5 fingers, sliding, holding, pressing, tapping in different ways, although I already tried it, it could very well be a valid answer for someone else so no downvote from me :)